# Django Debug Toolbar with DRF JWT

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-debug-toolbar

How can i use django debug toolbar with DRF and jwt authentication.
When using DRF with jwt auth, I cannot use the browser(DRF static files).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

```sh
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

or

```sh
django-admin collectstatic
```

[collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)

Comment: How can i pass jwt here ?
static files are not issue here.